# Using a single Jenkins job for building and running different subsets of unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, junit

As a preface, our setup is somewhat unusual due to "legacy" reasons. It is fully possible that I am going against the grain with this. I would love to get an expert opinion on whether it is possible to get my current setup working or a suggestion on a different approach.

### Environment

Java application with over 10K unit tests in JUnit. For legacy reasons the entire unit test run takes a long time (the ultimate goal is to fix the root of the problem, but this will not happen soon).

The application is broken up into multiple modules, with each module having its own unit tests. Executing tests module by module takes a reasonable amount of time, so that if someone commits the code to repo subtree with module's code and only module's tests get executed, they can get a result quickly.

### Current Jenkins Setup

#### JUnit job

This is the single *parameterized* job that can run tests for any module. The job takes in as parameters the regexs for which tests to run and a parameter indicating which module it is running, for notification purposes. It checks out *the whole* repo tree and then does the run based on the parameters.

After the completion of the run this job does the analysis of JUnits, publishes the report and sends out email notifications.

#### Repo watchers

One repo watcher for each module. The watcher checks out only the repo subtree that it wants to monitor. When a change is detected it triggers the JUnit job telling it which tests to run and for what component this is.

### Question

In general the setup works well, does exactly what I need, however it breaks a few of the nice and expected features of Jenkins and JUnit plugin.

1. Because the same job keeps executing different subsets of unit tests, the job to job comparison between unit tests does not provide any value. Without manually scanning between jobs it is not possible to tell what changed in terms of new failures or new fixes to unit tests.
2. Something very similar happens to change history: 
   Each repo watches runs on its own schedule. Suppose we have a change to module A and a change to module B, very close time wise to each other. If watcher A triggers first, the JUnit job triggered by watcher A will "claim" both changes. When the JUnit job triggered by watcher B runs, it will not detect any new changes in the repo. This plays havoc with email notifications, as the second JUnit job would not know who broke the build.

At the end of the day I believe I am looking for a way to establish dependency relationship between non sequential job runs in Jenkins for the same job, or alternatively a totally different approach.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so lets see if I get this right in basic language, 
You want to track what failures are caused by what changeset?

In which case I would suggest the following: Again in simple term - you need to adapt this to your current setup.

1. Setup a job that manages results
2. This job should be parameterized to take the name or change number and publish ALL the results.
3. This job should be triggered following each test run is completed to consolidate all results

now if a new test or failure is introduced the same job can track it and email the person who caused the failure.

Jenkins is very powerful and very generic so pretty much every secanrio if not plugins with groovy it can be resolved. So I would suggest taking a pen and map it on the board and create process of it rather than just a single job.

Comment: Thank you! As far as I understand Jenkins determines the change set by looking at the current SVN checkout and comparing the revision number to the last run of the same job. I believe you are suggesting having a job that does not do a checkout but just takes in a revision set and uses that to publish results? How do I do that?

Comment: Yes and OR you publish your test results in a folder and trigger the result job to consolidate that set over and over .
There are multiple plugins you can use to merge and display them you would need to look them up on Jenkins/plugins

Or you can write your own little executable that takes results as arguments and consolidates them.

Comment: Thank you, however I am not sure why this would work. The problem I am having is Jenkins keeping history between *consecutive* job runs. Even if I publish into another folder, as long as the job used to analyse the results is the same, I will hit the same problem. My question is about breaking dependency between consecutive runs, and finding a way to specify dependencies between non-consecutive ones.

Comment: I see what you mean - sorry I don't know a way of doing this.